# Market Basket Analysis in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, market-basket-analysis

I'm trying to do Market Basket Analysis in Tableau. In the image i attached, you will see a heat map (see image 1). For product 1 and product 2, the numbers of overlapping customers are shown in the heat map.
[image]

My question is that if it is possible to do another heat map to show the non-overlapping customers? The attached heat map is created by joining the same table to itself.(see image 2), so the logic is to join on customer ID. If i want to show non-overlapping customers who are the real potential business opportunities, may be joining the same table to itself is not the right way to go any more...Can anybody share some insights here? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First just a hint. I believe a heatmap is better visualized with colors, and not squares with varying sizes. So drag the CNT(Number of Records) to "Color", not "Size".

Now back to your question, I'm assuming you want the total number of orders with Product 1 that does not contain Product 2.

In that case, you need a table calculation:

```
TOTAL(SUM([Number of Records])) - SUM([Number of Records])
```

Then you need  to adjust the table calculation so it gets to sum the row or the column.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had profit on top of it actually, so the heat map was visualized with colors. i removed the profit measure just to show that i wanted to focus on the # of overlapping customers as the first step.

Comment: About the calculated field, i was not sure if that would work because eventually i want to show the details of non-overlapping customers, not just the sum number. For the heat map i attached, i have created an action to allow people to select the # of overlapping customers and show who are those customers on a separate sheet. If i do calculated field for non-overlapping customers, will i still be able to show who they are?

Comment: Good question. Best way to figure it out is testing. But as an intuition I would say it wouldn't work. The action will probably result in filtering the overlapping customers only, because you are basically selecting those 2 specific values for the dimension. If it is very important for you to be able to identify those customers, I would create another table with the inverse logic, i.e., put all the combinations of products that DON'T  appear on the basket. Troublesome, not immediate to do, but it would work